# an counterexample for The Density of Real Numbers Theorem?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, elementary-number-theory

[The Density of Real Numbers Theorem](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-density-of-real-numbers-theorem) says :

> Theorem 1 (The Density of Real Numbers): Let x,y∈R be any two real
>   numbers where x < y. Then there exists a rational number r ∈ Q such
>   that x < r < y.
>
> Corollary 1: Let x,y∈R be any two real numbers where x < y. Then there
>   exists an irrational number q∉Q such that x< q< y.

However , it seems I found out an counterexample that if x=0 and y=1/n (n=1,2,3,...) , then we cannot ensure there always exists a number within (0，1/n), especially when n→∞.

Did I make a mistake here?

Comment: Well, there won't be a rational that works for all $n$...but the theorem never said that there should be.  For any particular $n$, $0<\frac 1{2n}<\frac 1n$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The theorem deals only with two numbers at a time. For instance, $0$ and $\frac11$. Or $0$ and $\frac12$. Or $0$ and $\frac13$. Or...

It's always important to keep the hypothesis of a theorem in mind.

Answer (score 6):

While it's true that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}=0$, for each fixed $n$ there is always a rational number (in fact infinitely many) between $0$ and $\frac{1}{n}$. For instance, $\frac{1}{2n}$ works.